# PDFbox when rotating an image with scaling, the dimensions are smaller than without rotating

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm facing an issue that I'm drawing an image with PDFbox, when I draw it without rotation I got the correct dimensions but when I draw it with rotation the dimensions will be smaller.

Here are the images and the code:

Without rotation

[image: Without rotation image]

With rotation 45 degree

[image]

The code:

```
    public void placeImage(String imagePath, float x, float y, float rotation, float width, float height) throws Exception {
        File imageFile;
        boolean isTemp = false;
        if (imagePath.contains("http")) {
            imageFile = saveImageFromUrlToTempFile(imagePath);
            isTemp = true;
        } else {
            imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        }

        PDImageXObject imageToPutInside = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(imageFile, outputDocument);

        float newWidth;
        float newHeight;
        float imageHeight = imageToPutInside.getHeight();
        float imageWidth = imageToPutInside.getWidth();

        if (imageHeight > imageWidth) {
            newHeight = height > imageHeight ? imageHeight : height;
            newWidth = (newHeight * imageToPutInside.getWidth()) / imageToPutInside.getHeight();
        } else {
            newWidth = width > imageWidth ? imageWidth : width;
            newHeight = (newWidth * imageToPutInside.getHeight()) / imageToPutInside.getWidth();
        }

        x = x + ((width - newWidth) / 2);

        y = y + ((height - newHeight) / 2);

        y = calculateYAxisFromTop(y) - newHeight;

        outputPageContentStream.saveGraphicsState();

        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform(newWidth, 0, 0, newHeight, x, y);

        if(rotation != 0) {
            transform.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotation, 0.5, 0.5));
        }

        outputPageContentStream.drawImage(imageToPutInside, new Matrix(transform));

        outputPageContentStream.restoreGraphicsState();

        if (isTemp) {
            imageFile.delete();
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: try it the other way around, e.g. by using `preConcatenate` instead of `concatenate`.

Comment: Hi @mkl
I tried and this is the result
https://imgur.com/TZTQ7kU
  
I want to rotate the image about its center without making its dimensions smaller.

Comment: As you see the dimensions of the image, as far as it is visible, are still ok, you now merely have to fix the point around which it is rotated. I'll try to look into that next week if the issue is still open then.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I want to rotate the image around the center point, the issue still open, could you please help?

Comment: Bashar - are you still interested in this issue?